# Euclidean Distance in c#

Tags: c#, math

Can I calculate the Euclidean Distance in `int` type ?

```
    public static int ED(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2)
    {
        int square = (x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2);
        return square;
    }
```

I tried this, but if I add `Math.Sqrt` function, doen't work. What can I do ?

Comment: You didn't add it... (in your example)

Comment: I solved ... 'int square = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2)));'

Comment: You can also cast it: `int square = (int)Math.Sqrt((x1.....` instead of converting it.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a problem description. The compiler probably gave you a good hint as to the issue.

Comment: What if `x1 = y1 = 0` and `x2 = y2 = 1`? the actual distance is `sqrt(2) = 1.4142...`

Answer (score 3):

You have to change the output type to `double`:

```
//DONE: ED has to return double, not int
public static double ED(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2)
{
    return Math.Sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));
}
```

Even if coordinates are all `int`, the Euclidian distance is not necessary an *integer* value:

```
x1 = 0
y1 = 0
x2 = 1
y2 = 1
```

should return `sqrt(2) = 1.4142...`